Integrate semgrep into reNgine
reNgine is your go-to web application reconnaissance suite that's designed to simplify and streamline the reconnaissance process for security professionals, penetration testers, and bug bounty hunters. And semgrep is a sast tool. I want to integrate semgrep into reNgine, here is the source code on github of both:
https://github.com/semgrep/semgrep
https://github.com/yogeshojha/rengine
Does anyone have any ideas?
I don't have any idea for this problem
